# Is there any way to make EF save auto-compiled queries after DbContext has disposed?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I write web application that uses DbContext as unit of work (new instance per HTTP request).

The problem is that transtation IQueryable to string (SQL) is very slow.

EF 5 uses auto-compiled queries, but they work only until DbContext is disposed. After that all cached queries get lost.

So every HTTP request is slow, since Linq queries get compiled again.

Is there any way to make EF save auto-compiled queries after DbContext has disposed?

Comment: Auto compiled queries are cached per type of DbContext, so they are available even after dbcontext is disposed, other instance of same dbcontext type will use same cached queries, these queries are cached per application domain.

Comment: What is DbContext type? How to create DbContext of the same type?

Comment: DbContext type is your class derived from DbContext, you don't really do anything more to improve performance, however according to this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx , writing compiled query explicitly will result in 7% improvement in speed and it will be cached statically. This page has lots of comparison and guidance over improving speed.

Comment: Thanks. I finally get it works.

Comment: The query plan cache instance lives in the MetadataWorkspace's ItemCollection of store types. This means that cached store commands will be used for queries against any ObjectContext instantiated against a given MetadataWorkspace. It also means that if you have two connections strings that are slightly different and don't match after tokenizing, you will have different query plan cache instances.

Comment: Compiled queries will not work with a Dbcontext. It is also stated there (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3) that "Note that CompiledQueries are only compatible with ObjectContext-derived models, and not compatible with DbContext-derived models"